# Using $this when not in object context when reading cookies

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I'm attempting to read cookies inside a `Component` and getting an error in the `Cookie` class?

```
Using $this when not in object context
CORE\src\Http\Cookie\Cookie.php:738
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Code:

```
<?php
namespace WetKit\Controller\Component;

use Cake\Controller\Component;
use Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent;
use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\I18n\I18n;
use Cake\I18n\Time;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;
use Cake\Utility\Text;
use Cake\Http\Cookie\Cookie;
use Cake\Http\Cookie\CookieCollection;

class WetKitComponent extends Component
{
    public function init($configs = [])
    {
        ...
        debug(Cookie::read("wetkit.lang"));
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**Edit 2**

With the following code:

```
$cookieInstance = new Cookie('test'); 
debug($cookieInstance->read("wetkit.lang"));
```

I get:

```
Invalid data type, must be an array or \ArrayAccess instance.
InvalidArgumentException
Toggle Vendor Stack Frames
CORE\src\Utility\Hash.php:52
```

**Edit 3**

If I pass the request to my component like so:

```
//Setting core values for project
$this->appData = $this->WetKit->init([
    'request' => $this->request,
    ...
]);
```

Then, in my component:

```
debug($configs['request']->getCookie('wetkit.lang'));
```

I no longer get an error and it will output `null`. Unsure if this is a valid approach.

Comment: That's because you do not have an actual instance of your Cookie class here, but you are calling the method statically with `Cookie::read`. Since there is no object instance, there is no `$this` available either.

Comment: `$cookieInstance = new Cookie(); debug($cookieInstance->read("wetkit.lang"));` should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work. Even when I specify the string parameter to cookie, it fails somewhere else. Maybe I should pass the request up to my component somehow and get it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incorrect code usage aside, components can access the controllers they are attached to, and from there you can obtain the request object, from which you can then read cookies.

```php
$this->getController()->getRequest()->getCookie('wetkit.lang')
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Accessing a Component's Controller](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/components.html#accessing-a-component-s-controller)**
- **[Cookbook > Request & Response Objects > Cookies](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/request-response.html#cookies)**